# How to stop e.target from pointing to child elements in react?

Tags: reactjs, mouseover

I have a component (let's say a ) which has many sub components within it. i want to call a onmousemove event on this component. the event.target inside the call back function should always point to the div but when i hover over the child elements inside this the event.target is pointing to the child element being hovered over.

How do i make this event point to the main component always ?

```
  <div onMouseMove={(e) => this.test(e)}>
    <p>hello</p>
    <span>hi this is a test</p>
  </div>
  ..
  ..
  ..
  test(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
```

Expected output:

`<div>..</div>`     //always

Actual output:

`<div>..<div>` //when hovering over the div only part

`<p>..</p>`  //when hovering over p etc

Answer (score 2):

There is `e.currentTarget`, it points to the `div` expected by you